# Creating custom marker from vector image using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, symbology

I am relatively new to QGIS and I am working on an application based on PyQGIS. Right now, I am working on a kind of GPS which gets a set of points and returns the route  between these points as a rubberband.  For the starting and end point I am using 2 crosses which are QgsVertexMarkers. Although it's difficult to see them here's an example:

[image]

I would like these markers to be not a cross but rather the usual pin you can find at a GPS application:

[image]

But I can't find a way to define my own marker as vector image.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Could you please add the related code snippet showing how you added 2 crosses (QgsVertexMarker) to the canvas? So we can work on the code and may provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions :

If you want to use a **PNG** as icon you can go to property of your layer, then symbology (1), then click on the simple marker (2), then click on the list wich contain simple marker (3) and choose : Raster image marker. Click on the `...` box and choose your png file.

If you want to use a **SVG** as icon you can go to property of your layer, then symbology (1), then click on the simple marker (2), then click on the list wich contain simple marker (3) and choose : SVG marker. Go down to the last option and click on the `...` box and choose your SVG file.

Where to click :
[image]