# Change point with icon in QGIS using API

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, point, c++

I want to change points in the vector layer with an icon, which is an image in .png type using QGIS C++.

I found [Creating custom marker from vector image using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395704) but how can I do that programmatically using the C++ or Python API?

I tried the following for this purpose:

```
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap(":/mapMarker.png");
size = pixmap.size();
painter = new QPainter(&pixmap);

QgsSymbol *symbol = QgsSymbol::defaultSymbol(vecLayer->geometryType());
symbol->drawPreviewIcon(painter, size);
auto *vecRenderer = new QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol);
vecLayer->setRenderer(vecRenderer);
```

It compiles but when I run it, it crashes.

Comment: If you want to also ask about using PyQGIS to do this then please do so in a separate question that includes a code attempt

Comment: I actually added my approach.

Comment: @PolyGeo Might I know why this question was closed? I feel like this was a perfectly valid question. When I answered yesterday, the question already had a code snippet, so I don't think your comment about including a code attempt is very helpful

Comment: @CodeBard correct me if I’m wrong but the code attempt here is c++. So this one is fine as a c++ question. It’s just the Python question and a Python attempt that I think needs to be in a separate question.

Comment: It's not a Python question, it's a QGIS library question which has C++ and Python API. So answers in C++ or Python are both valid. One can switch from one to the other, right?

Comment: By C++ and Python I was writing shorthand for the QGIS C++ API and the QGIS Python API (PyQGIS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QgsRasterMarkerSymbolLayer`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterMarkerSymbolLayer.html) can be used to display a picture instead of the default point symbol. QGIS takes care of painting the icon and updating the preview icon, so there is no need to fiddle around with `QPainter` or `drawPreviewIcon` anywhere.

I've got a python example below. Shouldn't be too hard to adapt to c++, just replace the icon path to your need:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
path = r'D:\Projects\map.png'

symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry)
symbol.deleteSymbolLayer(0)

symbol_layer = QgsRasterMarkerSymbolLayer(path)
symbol.appendSymbolLayer(symbol_layer)

renderer = QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol)

layer.setRenderer(renderer)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```