# Change default point symbol with an icon in QGIS using API

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, point, vector, c++

I want to change default point symbol in the vector layer with an icon, which is an image in .png type using QGIS API.

I found a question "[Creating custom marker from vector image using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395704/creating-custom-marker-from-vector-image-using-pyqgis)", but this is to do it on QGIS Desktop application. How can I do the same thing programmatically using the C++ or Python API?

I tried the following for this purpose:

```
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap(":/mapMarker.png");
size = pixmap.size();
painter = new QPainter(&pixmap);

QgsSymbol *symbol = QgsSymbol::defaultSymbol(vecLayer->geometryType());
symbol->drawPreviewIcon(painter, size);
auto *vecRenderer = new QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol);
vecLayer->setRenderer(vecRenderer);
```

It compiles but when I run it, it crashes. Any lead in C++ or Python would be helpful.